# rearranging expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have been away from math for many years and just started  degree in mechanical engineering, one formula for calculating an unknown resistor value in a certain circuit is:

$\frac{R_1}{R_x + R_1} V_{in} = \frac{R_2}{R_2 + R_3}V_{in}$

In the example the expression becomes:

$R_x = R_1 \frac{R_2 + R_3}{R_2} - R_1$

I understand the logic of getting the unknown Rx on one side,  the part that gets me is how the formula gets rearranged below, i.e the Vin's getting cancelled, the -R1 etc..

Comment: Which formula has the $R_1$'s cancelled? Neither of your displayed formulas has that, and if you're solving for $R_x$ the "expression becomes" formula isn't right.

Comment: @coffeemath, yes sorry I meant the Vin's cancel, there are more parts to the whole calculation but in the example it goes from the top expression to the next in one step, I just need to understand the logic behind how we go from the first to the second

Answer (score 2):

The equation requires a little bit of context.
If I have guessed correctly,
first, it is supposed to be true for all $V_{\text{in}}$
(in practice, all $V_{\text{in}}$ up to some reasonable value for
which the circuit is rated); 
second, we assume that $R_1 \neq 0$ and $R_2 \neq 0$, 
because (in context) it makes no sense for $R_1$ or $R_2$ to be zero.

In any case, mathematically, in order to derive the new equation from
your initial equation, we must be able to assert at least that $V_{\text{in}} \neq 0$ and $R_2 \neq 0$.
Because $V_{\text{in}} \neq 0$, we know that $\frac{1}{V_{\text{in}}}$
is a number, so we can multiply the things on each side of the 
equation by $\frac{1}{V_{\text{in}}}$ and the resulting things will 
also be equal:

$$\frac{R_1}{R_x + R_1} V_{\text{in}} \cdot \frac{1}{V_{\text{in}}}
 = \frac{R_2}{R_2 + R_3} V_{\text{in}} \cdot \frac{1}{V_{\text{in}}},$$

which simplifies to

$$\frac{R_1}{R_x + R_1} = \frac{R_2}{R_2 + R_3}.$$

Now, since $R_2\neq 0$, we can multiply by $\frac{1}{R_2}$ as well.
Simplifying the result, we get

$$\frac{R_1}{R_x + R_1} \cdot \frac{1}{R_2} = \frac{1}{R_2 + R_3}.$$

Now multiply each side by $R_x + R_1$:

$$R_1 \cdot \frac{1}{R_2} = \frac{1}{R_2 + R_3} \cdot (R_x + R_1)$$

and multiply each side by $R_2 + R_3$:

$$R_1 \cdot \frac{R_2 + R_3}{R_2} = R_x + R_1.$$

Now subtract $R_1$ from both sides:

$$R_1 \cdot \frac{R_2 + R_3}{R_2} - R_1 = R_x.$$

Answer (score 1):

From $$\frac{R_1}{R_x + R_1} V_{in} = \frac{R_2}{R_2 + R_3}V_{in}
$$
after cancelling the common factor of $V_{in}$ and cross multiplying, it becomes
$$R_1(R_2+R_3)=R_2(R_x+R_1).$$
From here, $R_1R_2$ cancels from the sides and it becomes $R_1R_3=R_2R_x$ and this can be divided by $R_2$ to isolate $R_x.$

That gives $R_x=R_1R_3/R_2,$ and your second expression $R_1(R_2+R_3)/R_2-R_1$ is the same as $R_1R_3/R_2$ by algebra.